# Finding the 'Sign in' button on a webpage using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I'm new to Selenium and I'm trying to automate a login task on this [webpage](https://www.aero2astro.com/team/index.php/signin) using Chrome. I've been successful in  finding and sending keys to the email and password fields. However I'm unable to click the 'Sign in' button.

The inspect element yields the following,

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block mt15" type="submit">Sign in</button>
```

I've tried using

```
driver.find_element_by_name("Sign in").click()
```

which yielded in an error since there's no name field. I've found that this can be done using xpaths or css selectors.

Please Advise

Comment: Link_text is the right one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn").click()`

You can try this too.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Sign in").click()
```

The right selector would be above to grab a webelement by it's text.

Comment: `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate
 element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Sign in"}
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.150)`

Comment: Check if it has iframe before it. If it does then use driver switch to.